# Arrow not fitting text above it

Tags: graphics, chemfig

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOR)---)}
\arrow{->[hydrolisation][]}
\chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOH)---)}
\arrow{->}
\chemfig{**6(--(-[:-30](=[:-90]O)-[:30]O-[:-30]R)-(-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]O-[:30](*6(-(-OH)-(-OH)-(-OH)-(-COOH)-O-)))---)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Why doesn't my first arrow stretch to fit the word "hydrolisation" over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase arrow length with options [0,2] (0 is direction, 2 is length)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOR)---)}
    \arrow{->[hydrolisation][]}[0,2]
    \chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOH)---)}
    \arrow{->}
    \chemfig{**6(--(-[:-30](=[:-90]O)-[:30]O-[:-30]R)-(-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]O-[:30](*6(-(-OH)-(-OH)-(-OH)-(-COOH)-O-)))---)}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]